# SwiftUI overlay on top of NavigationView / NavigationBarTitle

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to position an overlay on top of the NavigationBarTitle / back button? In this example, I would like that the gray rectangle hides the navigationBarTitle and the "Back" button.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        EmptyView()
            .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)){
                
                NavigationView{
                    NavigationLink(destination: MyView(), label: {Text("Go to view")})
                }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 400, height: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .offset(y: -100)
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
            .zIndex(100) //doesn't do anything
            .navigationBarTitle("View")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need the navigation bar in this case? Maybe you can just hide it?

Comment: Unfortunately I do need it because I dynamically change the offset of the elements in the view.

Comment: Still, if you don't plan to use it, you can hide it and have just a rectangle on top. Could you explain why a rectangle is not enough, ie. why *dynamically change the offset of the elements in the view* will not work if you don't have a navigation bar?

Comment: Problem is I want that the navigation bar is visible. I implemented a custom list allowing the user to drag items around to change the order of the entries. So if the user moves the item upwards to the title, the item should be on top of the text and not the other way around. That'd look weird. @pawello2222